# send music to upnp device from PC

Tags: 14.04, pulseaudio, upnp

I have a new Arcam AirDAC (http://www.arcam.co.uk/products,rSeries,Wireless-DACs,airdac.htm) attached to my stereo which has upnp support.

I would like to send audio from my 14.04 PC to the box itself and to this end installed Rygel upon my system to help but it hasn't. I have created a new sound device in PulseAudioPreferences and selected it from inidcator-sound-switcher but here I become stuck.

The sound is heading to the new sound device as the volume can be seen to go up and down from PulseAudioVolumeControl but no sound comes from the stereo downstairs.

The problem, as I see it, is the new device has no idea where to send the music as the Arcam hasn't been chosen from any program.

So - I installed BubbleUPNP and Plex. My music has been imported into the later and the former can see both the Arcam as a Renderer and the Plex as the Media Server. Installing the BubbleUPNP program on my Android tablet allowed me to send music and all seemed good UNTIL I started playing AIFF and ALAC music and it all stopped. No suitable decoding device.

So that scuppered that route.

So here I am and stuck. How can I tell Ubuntu to use the Arcam as a renderer to play music through when the albums are played from Rhytmnbox, Tomahawk, Clementine or other?

Clementine would be my preferred client as there is a usable remote control program for the tablet. 
Can anyone help me fix this or advice another way to do what I would like?

Comment: Your Link Refers to Nothing and i guess you should shorten your Question so it's more understandable, or at least format it better!

Answer (score 0):

the best solution I have found for your exact problem (which is currently my problem, too!) is to use and install eezupnp (http://www.eezupnp.de/) and play through Ubuntu on that.

Eezupnp allows you to search through your music databases (local, or network upnp/dlna based) and play them out to DMRs (media renderers, which your AirCam will assumedly be detected as)

Eezupnp isn't as nice a solution as what you or I want, so it's not my final solution (I'm looking for one to work with Banshee, which seems to be receiving some UPnP work) but if I work something out, I'll let you know!

edit: After using Eezupnp a bit more, it seems very buggy with my device (XW SMA3 Pioneer Wireless Speaker). Songs in my playlist don't auto play all the time. Hopefully you have more luck.